# Asp.net mvc 3 - actioncontroller returning partialview another actioncontroller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, actioncontroller, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I would like to have an action controller which return a partialview of another actioncontroller.

```
public ActionResult Method1 (string s)
{
return PartialView (_PartialViewMethod1, object1);
}

public ActionResult Method2 ()
{
return PartialViewOfMethod1;
}
```

I tried this on method2: return PartialView (Method1(s)) but it does not work, how can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult Method2()
{
    string s = "someDefinedString";

    // instead of return PartialView(Method1(s));
    return Method1(s);
}
```

Comment: I tried this method very short to implement, works perfectly thanks all

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Method2 ()
{
return PartialView ("Method1", object1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the result you are looking for

```
public ActionResult Method2 ()
{
   return PartialView (_PartialViewMethod1, object1);
}
```

I guess you have some code which you have in common for both the action methods and that is why you want to call another action, then probably you move that to a common method and call that from wherever you want. Some Reactoring !

```
public YourViewModel GetData(srting s="")
{
  YourViewModel obj1=new YourVieWModel()
  // set some property values or do some operations to get data
  //your custom code
  return obj1; 
}

public ActionResult Method1 (string s)
{
  return PartialView (_PartialViewMethod1,  GetData(s));
}

public ActionResult Method2 ()
{
   return PartialView (_PartialViewMethod1, GetData());
}
```

Comment: I don' t know object1 till I call method1